# Add a unique ID to each item using cocoon gem - Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Regards! I am currently creating a buying and selling system, and for this I am supporting cocoon, which allows me to attach several items to the purchase, however I am trying to calculate the price per item before registering the purchase, but the current code calculates the price. first item, the others, no, clearly that is because each item must have a unique id, try attaching a Time.now, a SecureRandom.uuid, however, all the items inherit the same id and not from independent and unique, there is some way that cocoon provides a unique id to each item, and can be adapted to my code to calculate the prices per item, I appreciate your help

**input_item_fields.html.erb**

```
<tr class="item">
    <td><%= f.number_field :product_id %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :quantity, id: "quantity" %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :price, id: "price", class: "form-control is-valid" %></td>
    <td><%= f.number_field :utility %></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="result" readonly></td>    
    <td><%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, { wrapper_class: "item" } %></td>
</tr>

<script>
    $('#quantity, #price').keyup(function(){
        var cant = parseFloat($('#quantity').val()) || 0;
        var price = parseFloat($('#price').val()) || 0;
        var result = cant * price
        $('#result').val(result);
    })
</script>
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @input do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :invoice %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :invoice %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :provider %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :provider %>
  </div>

  <table border="1" class="mt-4" width="100%" id="product-item">
    <thead>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Utilidad</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Opciones</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <%= f.fields_for :input_items do |item| %>
        <%= render "input_item_fields", f: item %>
      <% end %>    
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class='links'>
    <br><%= link_to_add_association 'Agregar item', f, :input_items, :"data-association-insertion-node" => "table#product-item",:"data-association-insertion-method" => "append", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can use callbacks. For examples, see [this](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items)

Comment: Thanks for answering Kedarnag, could you give me an idea on how to apply this within the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you script: use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) of jQuery to get the element of current item's `<input type="text" id="result" readonly>` div and update that accordingly. Also, replace `id` with a `class` in the readonly input field. Like:

`<input type="text" class="result" readonly>`

And the script would be:

```
<script>
    $('#quantity, #price').keyup(function(){
        var cant = parseFloat(this.nextElementSibling('#quantity').val()) || 0;
        var price = parseFloat(this.nextElementSibling('#price').val()) || 0;
        var result = cant * price
        this.nextElementSibling('.result').val(result);
    })
</script>
```

This code is not tested, but maybe will work. Hope it'll help.

Comment: I thank you very much Emu, for giving me a hand, I just tried it, and I get an error: `TypeError: $ (...). NextElementSibling is undefined`, the error lines are:

`var cant = parseFloat($(this).nextElementSibling('#quantity').val()) || 0;
var price = parseFloat($(this).nextElementSibling('#price').val()) || 0;`

What do you think could be happening?

Comment: replace `$(this).nextElementSibling` with `this.nextElementSibling` and check the camel cases of **nextElementSibling**

Answer (score 0):

Regards! Unfortunately I could not solve the problem using the callbacks, I probably did not do it the right way, on the other hand, a user named Emeeus, gave me an answer that has come to solve the problem, and that has been good: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/189316/10663 (post is in Spanish), however I share the code here, for future references:

**_input_items_fields.html.erb**

```
<tr class="item">
    <td><%= f.number_field :product_id, class: "form-control is-valid" %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :quantity, class: "field quantity form-control is-valid" %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :price, class: "field price form-control is-valid" %></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="field subtotal form-control"></td>
    <td><%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, { wrapper_class: "item" } %></td>
</tr>

<script>

    $('.field').keyup(function() {
        var price = [];
        var quantity = [];

        $('.price').each(function(i, obj) {
            price.push(+obj.value);
        });

        $('.quantity').each(function(i, obj) {
            quantity.push(+obj.value);
        });

        console.log(price)
        console.log(quantity)

        var result = 0;

        price.map((o,i)=>{
        $(".subtotal").eq( i ).val(o*quantity[i]); 
        result += o*quantity[i];
        });

        $(".result").val(result); 
    })

</script>
```

**input_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @input do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :invoice %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :invoice %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :provider %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :provider %>
  </div>

  <div class="float-right">
    <label for="">Total</label>
    <input type="text" class="multi result">  
  </div>

  <table border="1" class="mt-4" width="100%" id="product-item">
    <thead>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <%= f.fields_for :input_items do |item| %>
        <%= render "input_item_fields", f: item %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class='links'>
    <br><%= link_to_add_association 'Add item', f, :input_items, :"data-association-insertion-node" => "table#product-item",:"data-association-insertion-method" => "append", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```